# Images won't load for certain website in Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

For now this only occurs with this website: http://www.panamajack.com (I want to buy a hat) and only in my installs of Ubuntu.

The images on the website *will not* load using any browser in my installs of Ubuntu 20 and 22 on different computers and I have tried the following without making any difference (in both Ubuntu releases on different computers):

- Chrome, Opera, Firefox as web browsers
- Incognito mode
- Shut off extensions (adblockers) in said browsers
- Set DNS nameservers to 208.67.222.22 and/or 8.8.8.8
- Tried different user agents with Chrome user agent spoofer extension
- Turned off Ubuntu firewall
- Javascript is turned on in browsers
- Tried different WiFi and wired networks other than home network

The same website loads correctly in Chrome (synced and with all extension enabled) and Edge with all images in Windows 10 and 11 instances in VirtualBox *on the same Ubuntu installs* on same WiFi (home) network.

The same website loads in Chrome on Windows 11 native and Safari and Chrome on iPad/iPhone on same WiFi (home) network.

This isn't a big deal, it's just driving me nuts that I can't figure it out.

Comment: Problem is with is the website... They probably check the browser string. Change the agent to what your windows browser uses and try again.  Check this one for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/121821/why-and-how-to-install-chrome-user-agent

Comment: I've tried every user agent available under the Chrome extension Chrome UA spoofer to no avail

Comment: I think @Rinzwind is correct. I cannot see any images either.

Comment: I've tried changing the browser agent to every one listed in Chrome's developer tools->...->More tools->Network conditions->User agent
It simply *will not* load images